# Is there a way to compare network-wide rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation

On Area 51, I can see that Jon Skeet has over 1M rep, and Gilles has 828k. But I doubt those are the highest.

So is there a way to compare network-wide rep?

Comment: Hint: Jon Skeet has the highest

Comment: Not necessarily. He's more of a specialist. There are others with 1M

Comment: Strike that. HE HAS MORE REPUTATION IN DOCS THAN SO. WHAT

Comment: I remember reading a query which listed users by network rep, and john skeet did have the highest. Trying to find it now.

Comment: Wait They are the same. Hmmmmmm

Comment: @bleh: Documentation is part of SO.  Any person you look at will have the same score on SO and on documentation because they are the same site.  That is documented in [How does "Reputation" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/315822) and [What is reputation?  How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).